# SQL Join using 4 different tables

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join, merge

I am a SQL beginner and trying to figure out what the following AND statement means in this SQL join

```
 LEFT JOIN [Galatasaray].[dbo].[Groups] ON [Ajax].[Flowers] = 
 [Groups].[Tree] 
 AND [Results].[BGF] = [Outcome].[label]
```

I am using the following pandas statement to refactor this in python, but I am not sure how to continue and include the AND statement.

```
Merge3 = pd.merge(Ajax, Galatasaray, on = 
'Flowers',how = 'left')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this,

```
Result_df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2,  how='left', left_on=['c1','c2'], right_on = ['c1','c2'])
```